# Twilio: How do I always place a "All calles are being monitored message" for incoming calls?

Tags: twilio

For incoming calls:

1) I am new to twilio, but I always want a "All calls are being monitored or recorded" to play for all incoming calls. What is the best way to do this?

2) I would like to create two messages after the "monitoring" message is played. one message during open hours and a second message during closed hours.

What is the best way to do this? Any good documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Welcome to using Twilio! I'll give you a quick overview of how incoming calls to Twilio work then point you to some useful parts of our documentation that will help you achieve what you are working towards.

[image]

When a Twilio phone number receives an incoming call, Twilio will send an HTTP request to your web application, asking for instructions on how to handle the call. Your web application will respond with an XML document containing TwiML. That TwiML contains the instruction that Twilio will follow to say some arbitrary text, play an MP3 file, make a recording and much more.

In your case you want to read messages to the caller, you could either do that by returning TwiML that uses [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) to read out the messages using our text to speech engine. Or you could record yourself reading the message and play that to the caller using the [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) TwiML.

To learn more:

- Follow the [Programmable Voice Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart?filter-product=voice)
- If you need more specific instruction on a particular Twilio feature, check out the [Twilio Guides](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides?filter-product=voice)
- If you need to see Twilio features as part of a complete application, check out the [Twilio Tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials?filter-product=voice) which cover more specific use cases

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Is there a way to private message you?

Comment: You can email me at philnash@twilio.com. Did my answer help at all? It's normally best to keep conversation in the open so that other's can learn from it too.

Comment: reviewing this: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/ivr-recording-rails. What are the correct request URLs if I am running this app on localhost for learning?

Comment: In development you need to open a tunnel to your localhost. We usually use a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com). Check out [this guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/voice/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-in-ruby#write-server-side-code-to-tell-twilio-how-to-handle-the-incoming-call) for a quick run down of how to use ngrok with Twilio.